# Repace node in leaf document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have the following yml file representing a localization file in a Ruby on Rails project:

```
es:
  animals:
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant
```

I need to add another category in the same level as animals to get the following result:

```
es:
  animals:
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant
  farm_animals:  # This key is new
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Sick elephant #This value changed
```

I would like to know if there is a way to duplicate a structure, overriding some specific values or nodes. I have tried the following:

```
es:
  animals: &animals
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant
  farm_animals:  
    <<: *animals
    sad_animals:
      elephant: Sick Elephant
```

However, this code overrides the whole sad_animals branch of the tree, while I just want to override a specific value, leaving the rest of the tree as it is. Is this possible with yaml?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
es:
  animals: &animals
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals: &sad_animals
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant
  farm_animals:  
    <<: *animals
    sad_animals:
      <<: *sad_animals
      elephant: Sick Elephant
```

---

```
2.3.0 :001 > yaml = <<-YALM
2.3.0 :002">     es:
2.3.0 :003">       animals: &animals
2.3.0 :004">         happy_animals:
2.3.0 :005">           dog: Dog
2.3.0 :006">           cat: Cat
2.3.0 :007">           horse: Horse
2.3.0 :008">         sad_animals: &sad_animals
2.3.0 :009">           cow: Cow
2.3.0 :010">           elephant: Elephant
2.3.0 :011">       farm_animals:  
2.3.0 :012">         <<: *animals
2.3.0 :013">         sad_animals:
2.3.0 :014">           <<: *sad_animals
2.3.0 :015">           elephant: Sick Elephant
2.3.0 :016"> YALM
2.3.0 :017"> Psych.load yaml
 => {"es"=>{"animals"=>{"happy_animals"=>{"dog"=>"Dog", "cat"=>"Cat", "horse"=>"Horse"}, "sad_animals"=>{"cow"=>"Cow", "elephant"=>"Elephant"}}, "farm_animals"=>{"happy_animals"=>{"dog"=>"Dog", "cat"=>"Cat", "horse"=>"Horse"}, "sad_animals"=>{"cow"=>"Cow", "elephant"=>"Sick Elephant"}}}}
```

As you can see, the `sad_animals` has a `Sick Elephant`:

```
"sad_animals"=>{"cow"=>"Cow", "elephant"=>"Sick Elephant"}
```